# A better way to replace the value of a global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a class

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self._arg = arg

    def execute(self):
        # execute business logic
        pass
```

Now, for reasons beyond my control, I need to have an instance of this class as a global somewhere.  However, I don't know what `args` should be when I define the global, so I just initially set it up as `None` and then later define it via a setter.

```
my_class = None

def set_my_class(arg):
   global my_class
   my_class = MyClass(arg)

def do_something():
   my_class.execute()
```

OK, so obvious problems here.

First, if the developer doesn't call `set_my_class`, then `my_class` is still `None` and we'll get some kind of error if we try to call `do_something`.

The second problem is PyCharm shows a warning on the `my_class.execute()` line because `None` doesn't contain the reference `execute`.

So, I'm looking for ideas on how to manage the global in this case and keep the compiler warnings to a minimum.  If I was writing Java, I would just use an interface.  But, I'm looking for a more Pythonic solution here.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the first issue. If the dev is the one to create an instance of the class because they are the one who knows the `args`, they would know that they have to instantiate it, no? And if they are not the one to do it, why can you not do it for them then?

Comment: Well, I mean you could always do `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` but I understand that it's not a satisfying solution.

Comment: Don't rely on global, mutable state. Here, just pass a `MyClass` object to `do_something`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate the responsibility to inside the class. Instead of assigning `my_class` with `None` - create an instance with `arg=None`. Then, in your `execute`, handle the case that it wasn't assigned. Something like:

```py
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        self._arg = arg

    def execute(self):
        if self._arg is None:
             raise ValueError("Didn't assign a proper value")
        # execute business logic
        pass

my_class = MyClass()
...
```

---

At that point, instead of creating a new instance and meddling with `global`s, you can just assign to `arg`:

```py
def set_my_class(arg):
    my_class._arg = arg
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if self._arg is None`?